# What is the best solution to present menu

Tags: ios, swift

I do have simple app with menu as shown in the picture
Can you please let me know what is the best solution to switch between different menu items? I would like to open menu select one from the list and menu window has to dismiss and selected menu item has to be presented. Do I have to use Delegate protocols or Observers?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom view and when menu button clicked add it as a subview with animation from bottom to top or as you like , with a delegate inside it so you can listen to click in that view's tableview cell , so in your current view controller navigate to the appropriate view controller

Comment: I would like to use my style of menu. I do not really like slide menu from your example.